# JavaScript / For loop contains other objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the next code:

```
var allFilesName = fs.readdirSync("./0/0");
console.log(allFilesName);
for (var i in allFilesName) {
 console.log("the num is: " + i + " in: " + allFilesName);
```

The output is:

```
[ '6', 'd' ]
the num is: 0 in: 6,d
```

Why it get `0`, when the `allFilesName` contains only `6` and `d`?

Comment: `readdirSync` returns an **array**. Use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: and the key is still zero, to access the value you'd do `allFilesName[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` = the index of element in array. if you want the element itself - use that:

```
   console.log("the num is: " + allFilesName[i] + " in: " + allFilesName);
```

Answer (score 0):

for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order is important. Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.

Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.forEach or the non-standard for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where the order of access is important.  [My Ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Try to work with the regular for loop it worked fine with me

```
var allFilesName = [ '6', 'd' ];
for (var i=0; i <= allFilesName.length; i++) 
{
 console.log("the num is: " + i + " in: " + allFilesName);
}
```